# Best way to implement long running and dependency tests

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jenkins

We have integration tests. Most of them are simple but we have couple use cases when we should prepare data and checks them than wait for 5 hours. Prepared data should be processed by system daemons and we should check them again after 5 hours.

Our problems:

1. if we put all tests as single project then we will see test results only in 5 hours, is there way in jenkins to see current tests result status?
2. what is the best practice to implement test where phase_A runs and after couple hours phase_B runs and it depends on phase_A

Comment: Why do you have to wait 5 hours?  Could you split the test into two so that they can run immediately?

Comment: Yes, but second one should be run after 5 hours then first one.

Answer (score 0):

Since the tests are dependent on each other and you are concerned with the integration of the two processes.  I would say you want to change the testing so that it takes significantly less than 5 hours to complete.

Consider moving the time difference to a configuration file so that in testing, for example set the time to 5 seconds.  This would be similar to setting database connections to a testing database rather than your production one.  Your main concern being that the results of Process_A occur some time interval after Process_B and the two need to interact.